# There is a known bug for the wireless card for my Lenovo ThinkPad T440 running 12.04. What are my options?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am trying to get wireless working on my Lenovo ThinkPad T440, running Ubuntu 12.04. I think I have a Realtek 818b wireless card.

```
$ lspci | grep -i Net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 818b
```

It seems as if there is a [known problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1239578) with the drivers for this wireless card.

What are my options for what to do next? Update to a newer version of Ubuntu? Wait for a bug fix? I am fairly new to open source. What are my options in this situation?

Comment: I can't tell you how to get the wireless card working if it is not yet supported. I would recommend buying a $10 USB wifi adapter. They are tiny so you will hardly notice it is there. Just make sure to read customer reviews to confirm that it works out of the box with Linux.

Comment: Have you tried again with linux-3.16-rc1 or linux-3.16-rc2 yet? Hopefully the wait for support of this particular (RTL8192EE) driver is almost over.

Comment: @binki are those flavors of ubuntu? LTS is probably more important to me than a working wireless driver

Comment: They’re not editions of ubuntu but, rather, testing/unstable/release candidates for the Linux kernel itself. It will probably take a while for Ubuntu LTS to get a kernel as new as 3.16, especially as there is no final release of that version yet. If you want to keep your system clean and not mess with experimental kernel versions, then you’ll have to wait…

Answer (score 2):

The bug report you linked confirms that the driver is not included in Ubuntu 14.04. "Trusty: Confirmed." The driver can be compiled in 13.10, however it is unreliable: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206565&highlight=rtl8192ee I suggest you wait until a better driver is developed; check here and on ubuntuforums.org.

Until that time, the advice above, to get a USB wireless, is sound.