# How can I find a USB wireless adapter that will work with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, networking, usb

There is a bug for my wireless card on Ubuntu 12.04. [There is a known bug for the wireless card for my Lenovo ThinkPad T440 running 12.04. What are my options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425604/there-is-a-known-bug-for-the-wireless-card-for-my-lenovo-thinkpad-t440-running-1)

In order to get wireless on the machine running I will need to buy a usb wireless card. How can I find a USB wireless card that I can be 100% sure will work with Ubuntu 12.04? Is there a list of known supported hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Panda makes very Linux  friendly USB dongles. Look them up on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with 2 USB wifi adapters.

- If you have a strong WiFi signal, Ralink/Mediatek RT5370 (N150) adapters seem to work well but signal strength doesn't indicate very strong. The best speed I've seen indicated is 72.5 mb./sec. Tenda W311Mi is one example.
- If your wifi signal is weaker, I find RealTek RTL8192SU chip based adapters quite good and also plug -n- play in my experience.  I've had good luck with TrendNet TEW-649UB. This chip is supposed to support 300 down, 150 up.

If you go with the TEW-649UB adapter, you may have an issue with networking not starting after suspend. A one line file should solve the issue. From an account with SUDO authorization, type the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

A new empty file will be created.  type one line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="R8712U"
```

Save and reboot.  That should fix any suspend/resume problem. My Trendnet devices tend to run a bit warm so suspect they use more battery power than the MediaTek/Ralink device is that matters to you. I hope this helps.